# how to hide selectbox when no options

Tags: jquery, arrays, select

How can I hide a selectbox when there a less then two options present? 
I've made a small script that automatically adds options to a selectbox. This works excellent. Problem however is that the next selectbox is showed even when there are no options to display. How to fix that?
I tried it myself with the piece of code all the way down between ///////

HTML

```
  <div class="zoeken-select">
    <div class="zoeken-value" id="cat1">Selecteer je school/opleiding</div>
    <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
    <select id="school" class="gui-validate">
      <option>Selecteer je school/opleiding</option>
                <option value="566342">Riemen</option>
                <option value="566347">Sjaals</option>
                <option value="566348">Tassen</option>
                <option value="566341">Kleding</option>
                <option value="566345">Sale!</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="zoeken-select course">
    <div class="zoeken-value" id="cat2">Selecteer je sector/locatie</div>
    <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
    <select id="course" class="gui-validate">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="zoeken-select list" style="display:none;">
    <div class="zoeken-value" id="cat3"></div>
    <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
    <select id="list" class="gui-validate">
    </select>
  </div>
  etc....
```

JQUERY

```
// opleiding
            var courseSelection = {
             "566342": [ { value: "566343", text: "Dames riemen" },{ value: "566344", text: "Heren riemen" },],
             "566347": [ ],
             "566348": [ ],
             "566341": [ ],
             "566345": [ { value: "566346", text: "Tassen" },],

             };

            $("select#school").change(function(){

              $("select#course").html('<option value="">Kies je opleiding</option>');
              $("select#list").html('<option value="">Kies een lijst</option>');

              $("#cat1").html($("#school option:selected").text());
              $("#cat2").html('Kies je opleiding');
              $("#cat3").html('Kies een lijst');
              $("#cat4").html('Kies ');
              $("#cat5").html('Kies lijst');

              var options = '',
                  courses = courseSelection[$(this).val()];

              $('select#course').empty();

              options += '<option value="">Kies je opleiding</option>';

              $.each(courses, function() {
                options += '<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.text + '</option>';
              });

              $('select#course').append(options);
              $('.zoeken-select.course').fadeIn(300);

            });
            // end opleiding

            // lijst
            var listSelection = {
               "566343": [ ],
               "566344": [ { value: "707274", text: "tyesr" },],
               "566346": [ ],
            };

            $("select#course").change(function(){

              $("#cat2").html($("#course option:selected").text());

              var options = '';
              lists = listSelection[$(this).val()];

              $('select#list').empty();

              options += '<option value="">Kies je lijst</option>';

              $.each(lists, function() {
                options += '<option value="' + this.value + '">' + this.text + '</option>';
              });

              $('select#list').append(options);

              ///////////////////////////////////////////
              if ( $("select#list option[value='" + options + "']").val() <= 2) { 
                $('.zoeken-select.list').hide();
              } else {
                $('.zoeken-select.list').show();
              }
              //////////////////////////////////////////
            });    
            etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) like,

```
if ( $("select#list option").length <= 2) { //check length of options not value
    $('.zoeken-select.list').hide();// use hide() in place of show()
} else {
    $('.zoeken-select.list').show();
}
```

Comment: If you already know the value why do you retrieve it with .val() ?

Comment: @Rohan Kumar: Off course it needs to be hide(). Made a typo. That doesn't work because the select box is hidden whatever the amount of options

Comment: @Virus721: The "array" is filled automatically. So I don't really know the value. Or do I understand you the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if ( $("#list>option").length <= 2) { 
  $('.zoeken-select.list').hide();
} else {
  $('.zoeken-select.list').show();
}
```

I check the direct number of children under the select with id list. If the count is less than 2, I hide using jquery's hide method(Implicitly it just sets the element's display style to none). If not, I show using jquery's show method(Sets display to block).

Comment: Can you add a bit of an explanation to your answer, it's a little thin on the ground as is. Thanks.